# Monetize subomain website with Google AdSense

Tags: adsense

Can someone help me to monetize my website with AdSense?

I have this domain: **danielemenchetti.com** with this subdomain: **server.danielemenchetti.com**.

I want to monetize **server.danielemenchetti.com** with AdSense.

Do someone know how to do (each single step)?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my solution, you need to have an active adsense account with approval for danielemenchetti.com

What you all have to do is,

- Goto Adsense Dashboard
- Goto Sites
- Click on the domain and select "View Details"
- Click "Add Subdomain" in top right corner
- Enter your subdomain